# Can anyone suggest me a good plugin for wordpress 4.4 that shows powerpoint presentation?

Tags: wordpress, presentation, powerpoint

I was building a website for my organization. For that purpose I am using WordPress 4.4 as my CMS. I am new in this environment. We are going to share power point presentation in our website. So can anyone suggest me a good plugin that can help me out. Or any suggestion on that purpose. For your better understanding I have shared some of the links of website where this kind of thing is done.

It should also allow the PPT file to be downloaded.

http://www.authorstream.com/Presentation/aSGuest48405-412050-WordPress-what-is-wordpre-Entertainment-ppt-powerpoint/

http://www.slideshare.net/Johndigitalmaina/importance-of-having-a-website-presentation

Comment: Should it be free? Should it allow the file to be downloaded?

Comment: Yeah.....it allow the file to be downloaded...